# Filter data by using nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, opendata

from one API I am getting these type of response. I need to get latitude, longitude of single entity. How can I filter this data by using javascript (node js).

```
header {
  gtfs_realtime_version: "1.0"
  incrementality: FULL_DATASET
  timestamp: 1501132018
}
entity {
  id: "1"
   vehicle {
       trip {
               trip_id: "141.180717.42.1145"
               schedule_relationship: SCHEDULED
               route_id: "4T.C.141"
            }
   position {
               latitude: -29.77179
               longitude: 151.11717
               bearing: 90.00001
            }
               timestamp: 1501131987
               congestion_level: UNKNOWN_CONGESTION_LEVEL
               stop_id: "23604"
   vehicle {
               id: "141"
               label: "11:45am (141)  Grafton City - Moree Town"
           }
  }
}
entity {
  id: "2"
  vehicle {
    trip {
      trip_id: "511.160717.90.1416"
      schedule_relationship: SCHEDULED
      route_id: "4T.C.511"
    }
    position {
      latitude: -32.09544
      longitude: 148.06787
      bearing: 313.0
    }
    timestamp: 1501131974
    congestion_level: UNKNOWN_CONGESTION_LEVEL
    stop_id: "28211"
    vehicle {
      id: "511"
      label: "02:16pm (511)  Dubbo - Bourke"
    }
  }
}
```

All these data are of transportation API. If it would have been in JSON then we can get it by using foreach and by using its index.

Comment: What kind of filtering are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i need latitude and longitude of the second record.

Comment: Ok, what's stopping you from just grabbing that data? e.g. if the JSON object is called `result` you access the member with `result.entity.position.latitude`

EDIT: side note that JSON above does not look valid, please post the correct JSON with it's form intact so we can help

Comment: this is the exact form that I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript map function and extract only those fields which you want.